# C++ find out which operator= is used?

Tags: c++

I have a code section of the form

```
auto myObject = someFunc <T> ();
```

`someFunc` returns an object of type `T` by value.

Despite setting `T& T::operator= ( T const& other )` and `T& T::operator= ( T && other )` to private. I get no compiler error.

How do I find out what the expression actually uses?

Comment: Might not be either in case of copy/move ellision: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision

Comment: Ok, final edit: The object has a mutex. I don't know if this might yield problems. Can I check whether this is going on?

Comment: To determine if this can cause problems the question needs more context, e.g.: a [mre]

Comment: The constructors have mutexes too on the other object.

Comment: `operator =` is **never used** when the code has the form of `type_name variable_name = intializer`.  This is copy initialization and uses a constructor.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Indeed. Could you turn this into a full answer so I can mark yours as answer?

Comment: @NathanOliver in modern versions, yes. But that wasn't always the case in older versions.

Comment: @RemyLebeau That's been the case since day one of C++98.  `operator =` is only used for assignment and `type_name variable_name = intializer` is initialization, not assignment.

Comment: @NathanOliver I seem to recall that `type_name variable_name = type_name(params);` did in fact originally use default construction and assignment until recent years, when it was changed to optimize construction to act like `type_name variable_name(params);` instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau That never used assignment but recently it was changed from generating a temporary and then doing a copy operation to just being optimized to a single construction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
auto myObject = someFunc <T> ();
```

no `operator =` is used.  When you have

```
type_name variable_name = intializer
```

you are declaring and initializing an object and only constructors are used to initialize an object.

`operator =`  is only used when you are doing assignment, and that only occurs after you've defined a variables.

In your code depending on a number of conditions you will either see return value optimization (RVO) or named return value optimization (NRVO) meaning you will only see one constructor call or a copy/move operation will happen and you will see two constructor calls happen.  One for the object created in `someFunc` and the other to copy/move that value into `myObject`.

---

```
type_name variable_name = intializer; // initialization
variable_name = something;            // assignment
```

Comment: RVO and NRVO are relevant in the function's implementation, not outside...

Comment: since OP mention `private` `operator=` I think It'd be helpful to also add (normal) RVO cannot bypass private copy constructor.